# How to login in Facebook using mvn project with java

Tags: facebook, maven, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, restfb

I have to create a mvn java application, which must give the possibility to log on facebook and returning the user id and the user access token. i've already read the facebook guide but the code to obtaint that result is in js.
Anyone have any ideas or know any valid frameworks? I have already read the restFb documentation but according to old questions posted on stack, that frameworks is obsolete.

Comment: Using RestFB you can start with this example: https://github.com/restfb/restfb-examples/tree/dev The run-login-example uses a JavaFX Browser or you can use the device login.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.